# youtube-dl get direct download url

Tags: php, python, download, youtube, youtube-dl

Is there a way to get the direct download URL using youtube-dl?

I tried it with `youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx`

It returns a URL that looks correct at the first sight, but it leads to a blank page that shows the video player. I want to extract the direct download URL like the example below.

Link to player: `https://r4---sn-fpoq-cgpl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&key=yt6&itag=22&lmt=1476010871066368&source=youtube&upn=4B17cM_dGEU&ei=cNdSWM7CKMjMigbzv62ADA&ip=151.45.98.20&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=695000&ms=au&mt=1481824045&mv=m&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&id=o-AHTIR887C2uesvqaEJtgUJhaFssm050soDMhiXfgLQ1f&pl=16&mm=31&mn=sn-fpoq-cgpl&ipbits=0&dur=226.649&ratebypass=yes&expire=1481845712&signature=34BB16F2B7F758CA44680A778F46AC49EBCA3BE3.B0452B32B62D4AA133BA2F59E78EFD66FEA6298D`

Direct Link to file: `https://r4---sn-cu-n1qs.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AFc2eS8nuL2DLN608O3_QxaAQWNDCeIRl9oGTvRo-fKM&ip=81.140.223.31&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2,pcm2cms,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&ei=qdVSWOP7BIK7WaTrkdgM&dur=226.649&pl=25&initcwndbps=1175000&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&pcm2cms=yes&requiressl=yes&pcm2=yes&expire=1481845257&key=yt6&mime=video/mp4&ipbits=0&lmt=1476010871066368&itag=22&mv=m&mt=1481823436&ms=au&mn=sn-cu-n1qs&mm=31&upn=6EUZ1r48CCw&signature=9F514204B90A32936912E5134B58BD8200177AF1.5A5C8BAC42B32C62229D078F0B566890F7DA524B&&title=Bruno+Mars+-+24K+Magic+%5BOfficial+Video%5D`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Usage of `youtube-dl` is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer myself, I don't know why but to generate a download URL the only things to do is add the title at the end of the URL, so adding `&title=Bruno+Mars+-+24K+Magic+%5BOfficial+Video%5D` at the end of the first URL solved my problem.

Comment: Did you find it? Because I went to both of your links with &title=Bruno+Mars+-+24K+Magic+%5BOfficial+Video%5D added to the end and my browser is saying Google denied me authorization to the address

Comment: Yes because the link extracted only works for the IP address from which it was extracted. Try to extract the link yourself then add the decoded title to the end of the string.